# Image.FromHbitmap WPF equivalent

Tags: wpf, winforms, system.drawing

Is there a System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap equivalent in WPF?
Also, is it possible to dispose the handle properly after creating an image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap.aspx) in the System.Windows.Interop namespace.